# How to refine number permutations for efficiency

Tags: python, performance, permutation

I am working on a dice probability program and have been running into some efficiency issues in the permutation section when the numbers get big.  For example, the perimeters I am required to run are 10 dice, with 10 sides, with an outcome of 50.

I require a total number of permutations to calculate the probability of the specified outcome given the number of dice and number of sides.  The `final_count(total, dice, faces)` function lets the least number of combinations pass from the generator before moving into the `perms(x)` function.

The following code works, but for the previously mentioned perimeters it takes an extremely long time.

The `perms(x)` was posted by @Ashish Datta from this thread:
[permutations with unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284396/permutations-with-unique-values)
Which is where I believe I need help.

```
import itertools as it

total = 50
dice = 10
faces = 10

#-------------functions---------------------

# Checks for lists of ALL the same items
def same(lst):
   return lst[1:] == lst[:-1]

# Generates the number of original permutations (10 digits takes 1.65s)
def perms(x):
    uniq_set = set()
    for out in it.permutations(x, len(x)):
        if out not in uniq_set:
            uniq_set.update([out])
    return len(uniq_set)


# Finds total original dice rolls.  "combinations" = (10d, 10f, 50t, takes 0.42s)
def final_count(total, dice, faces):
    combinations = (it.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, faces+1), dice))
    count = 0
    for i in combinations:
        if sum(i) == total and same(i) == True:
            count += 1
        elif sum(i) == total and same(i) != True:
            count += perms(i)
        else:
            pass
    return count

# --------------functions-------------------

answer = final_count(total, dice, faces) / float(faces**dice)

print(round(answer,4))
```

I have read the thread [How to improve permutation algorithm efficiency with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885641/how-to-improve-permutation-algorithm-efficiency-with-python).  I believe my question is different, though a smarter algorithm is my end goal.

I originally posted my first draft of this program in CodeReview.  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212930/calculate-probability-of-dice-total.  I realize I am walking a fine line between a question and a code review, but I think in this case, I am more on the question side of things :)

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem you're trying to solve.  Is this all permutations (or combinations) of 10D10 that total to 50?  If so, then you're spending a *lot* of time by generating and checking *all* combinations.  Rather, a recursive "sum-to-target" algorithm could reduce that time.

Comment: Thank you.  I edited my question to clarify.  
I require a total number of permutations to calculate the probability of the perimeters.  finding the unique combinations only takes 0.42s

Comment: @Prune
I think I am using a "sum-to-target" approach by creating a combinations generator and then accessing them for my functions.  Unless I am misunderstanding what this means.

Comment: No, but the answer you accepted is exactly that class of algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function that deducts the current dice rolls from the totals for the recursive calls, and short-circuit the search if the total is less than 1 or greater than the number of dices times the number of faces. Use a cache to avoid redundant calculations of the same parameters:

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def final_count(total, dice, faces):
    if total < 1 or total > dice * faces:
        return 0
    if dice == 1:
        return 1
    return sum(final_count(total - n, dice - 1, faces) for n in range(1, faces + 1))
```

so that:

```
final_count(50, 10, 10)
```

returns within a second: `374894389`

Comment: This is fantastic!  Definitely above my head, but thats how we learn :)   
Can't import lru_cache for some reason though.  functools isn't 3rd party is it?

Comment: Glad to be of help. `functools.lru_cache` is only available since Python 3.3, so if you're using an earlier Python version then you would have to install a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/backports.functools_lru_cache/) of it.

Comment: BINGO!  ATOM defaults to python2 -> fixed.  Thank you.

Thank you for posting that.  I'm going to see if I can dig into the process in pythontutor to see how it all happens.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar solution to blhsing but he beat me to it and, to be honest I didn't think of using lru_cache (nice! +1 for that).  I'm posting it anyhow if only to illustrate how storage of previously computed counts cuts down on the recursion.

```
def permutationsTo(target, dices, faces, computed=dict()):
    if target > dices*faces or target < 1: return 0 
    if dices == 1 :                        return 1
    if (target,dices) in computed: return computed[(target,dices)]
    result = 0 
    for face in range(1,min(target,faces+1)):
         result += permutationsTo(target-face,dices-1,faces,computed)
    computed[(target,dices)] = result
    return result
```

Comment: I couldn't import lru_cache for some reason, so I gave yours a go.  It worked amazing, except for if the target is 0.  Easily fixed for my purposes, but thought i'd mention the bug.

Comment: Fixed it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

One way to greatly reduce the time is to mathematically count how many combinations there are for each unique group of numbers in `combinations`, and increment `count` by that amount.  If you have a list of n objects where x1 of them are all alike, x2 of them are all alike, etc., then the total number of ways to arrange them is n!/(x1! x2! x3! ...).  For example, the number of different ways to arrange the letters of "Tennessee" is 9!/(1! 4! 2! 2!).  So you can make a separate function for this:

```
import math
import itertools as it
import time

# Count the number of ways to arrange a list of items where
# some of the items may be identical.
def indiv_combos(thelist):
    prod = math.factorial(len(thelist))
    for i in set(thelist):
        icount = thelist.count(i)
        prod /= math.factorial(icount)
    return prod

def final_count2(total, dice, faces):
    combinations = it.combinations_with_replacement(range(1, faces + 1), dice)
    count = 0
    for i in combinations:
        if sum(i) == total:
            count += indiv_combos(i)
    return count
```

I don't know off-hand if there's already some built-in function that does the job of what I wrote as `indiv_combos2`, but you could also use `Counter` to do the counting and `mul` to take the product of a list:

```
from operator import mul
from collections import Counter

def indiv_combos(thelist):
    return math.factorial(len(thelist)) / reduce(mul, [math.factorial(i) for i in Counter(thelist).values()],1)
```

I get mixed results on the times when I try both methods with `(25, 10, 10)` as the input, but both give me the answer in less than 0.038 seconds every time.